# How to convert string to BSON using MongoDB C++ driver?

Tags: json, mongodb, type-conversion, bson

Similar to [toString](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj.html#ab5ce53a72b938d231a019a921ea8f1f2) is there a way we can convert a string to BSON object? I need to remove a document using C++ driver the the remove function expects the query to have BSON object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the fromjson method found here:

http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/1.5.4/namespacemongo.html#a4f542be0d0f9bad2d8cb32c3436026c2

```
BSONObj mongo::fromjson (   const string &  str  )  
Create a BSONObj from a JSON <http://www.json.org> string.
```

> In addition to the JSON extensions extensions described here
>       http://mongodb.onconfluence.com/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON, this function accepts
>       certain unquoted field names and allows single quotes to optionally be used when
>       specifying   field names and string values instead of double quotes. JSON unicode escape
>       sequences (of the form ) are converted to utf8.
>
> Exceptions:
>       MsgAssertionException if parsing fails. The message included with this assertion includes
>       a rough indication of where parsing failed.